# Installing BusyBox crashes phone

Tags: installation, crashes, busybox

I'm trying to install [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) on my rooted stock Droid DNA.

Every time I try the normal install, it fails saying that the program can't be installed in `/system/bin`. If I do the smart install, it crashes and restarts the phone.

Anything I can do to make it work?

**Edit** so I looked through the busybox applet manager and about 20-30% are installed/symlinked by the smart install before it crashed the phone. I don't know if this is going to make a difference.

Also, would I be better off not doing it this way and installing through clockwork mod or adb?

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: Yeah. Stock Rom, but I am rooted, and I have superuser installed with BusyBox allowed. Maybe a silly question, but how big is busybox to install? It says I have 450mb free in system.

Comment: Should I try installing it to /system/xbin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work by using ES File Explorer to mount system as writeable.
I did a NAndroid backup first in case I needed to start over again, but after mounting system, it appears that it installed like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

I too have a HTC DNA but did not want to root my phone so I just did it the "non-root" way with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=burrows.apps.busybox.

This way I am not voiding any boot-loaders or warranties.

```
Required:
✔ Android Terminal Emulator Application
After having a rooted phone for years, I know that there are plenty of applications that allow users to customize their phones; however, when I recently bought a brand new phone this year, I decided not to root it and I realized the main reason for rooting my phone was simply to obtain more linux tools. I made this simple application in order to help users simply install BusyBox without the hassle of being rooted!
All binaries are installed in: /data/data/burrows.apps.busybox/app_busybox/
In Terminal Emulator, Preferences: Initial command: export PATH=$PATH:/data/data/burrows.apps.busybox/app_busybox/
Provided extra Binaries:
✔ add-property-tag
✔ backup
✔ bash
✔ btool
✔ check-lost+found
✔ dexdump
✔ drm1_func_test
✔ hcidump
✔ hcitool
✔ iwmulticall
✔ latencytop
✔ librank
✔ micro_bench
✔ multitouch
✔ nano
✔ opcontrol
✔ openvpn
✔ oprofiled
✔ procmem
✔ procrank
✔ rawbu
✔ run_backup
✔ run_restore
✔ sane_schedstat
✔ scheduler
✔ scp
✔ showmap
✔ showslab
✔ sqlite3
✔ ssh
✔ ssmgrd
✔ strace
How to use BusyBox Non-root:
✔ Step 1: Click on "Install" to install BusyBox
✔ Step 2: Open your Terminal and change directory to the path!
Permissions requested:
✔ Internet: Download BusyBox (make sure you are on WiFi!)
✔ Script: Add PATH to Terminal
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following:

1. Check that `/system` is mounted as read-write. You can either check the mount filesystem or just try to copy a file with a root explorer to it.
2. Check that `/system` filesystem is not full and you have enough space.

As for the install, I would use the smart install in this case, since it won't overwrite all commands present in your ROM. If you find you still can't install it on `/system/bin` you could try to install it in `/system/xbin`.

If you find that `/system` is mounted in read only and you can't install it with that app, then you should install busybox from a flashable zip through recovery.

Comment: According to the busybox installer, system has 430mb. Can I free space there somehow? I think it is mounted because smart installer did install some things before it crashed, according to the app some things are installed/symlinked. Would I be better off just using recovery?

Comment: If I install to xbin, will it be a problem that some things installed to bin?

Comment: You have enough space in `/system`. If you install busybox to xbin, the app will create links in `/system/bin` that will point to the executable, so there won't be any problem. Busybox is just one executable file and the app creates links to call it directly.

Comment: Ok, looks like I'm going to have to do the flashable zip... Any ideas where to get it? Busybox.net has a lot of options, but I don't know which one is right for my phone. and it looks like it has to be built, which I don't know how to do...

Answer (score 0):

What is your version? Because version 9.0 a had bug which crashed the mobile it seems. He fixed it in 9.1 and it got to play store on January 29th.

Comment: That's a good question... I ended up doing a factory reset and then just restoring the apps, and didn't restore busybox at that time, but the titanium backup date for busybox before the reset was Feb 5th, and I'm pretty sure I had the most up to date version at that time. I may try it again, but I really don't want to go through the hastle of having to factory reset (I was running into problems where the launcher would get corrupted every time I restarted, and if I restorted it from backup it would be gone again the next time I restarted. Also, settings was corrupted and could not be restored)

Comment: Well. Give a try :)

Comment: I might over the weekend... reloading everything wasn't all that fun. I just wish there was a way to roll it back if it gets part way and dies again.